# How to change the design of input type="color"?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Is it possible to change the design of `input type="color"`?
I want to change the design like below (for mobile apps).

[image]

I've been doing some research, but I don't know how.

```
<input type="color" name="favorite_color" onChange={handleSliderChange2}></input>
```

Comment: You can override the appearance of almost any browser-rendered (“replaced”) element, like inputs, with CSS’s `appearance:` property but but you’ll basically have to reimplement everything - also the color picker’s popup is not exposed to the DOM (OS-provided dialogs are opaque, after-all). So, what are you **really** trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper` and `::-webkit-color-swatch` pseudo classes are available to style type color input

Comment: This is not a cross-platform solution though (e.g. Firefox uses `-moz-color-swatch-wrapper`) and it only configures the appearance of a “closed” color input, not the expanded/open/popup part of the color picker.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make Your Own Slider.Using an `input[type:range]` with values from 0 to 10 & changing the color of the `.colorPreview` & thumbColor with Switch Case.

```js
let colorPicker = document.querySelector("#color-picker");
let colorPreview = document.querySelector(".color-preview");

function colorSlider() {
  let Cvalue = parseInt(colorPicker.value);
  switch (Cvalue) {
    case 0:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'red');
      break;
    case 1:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'pink');
      break;
    case 2:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'yellow');
      break;
    case 3:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'blue');
      break;
    case 4:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "teal";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'teal');
      break;
    case 5:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'black');
      break;
    case 6:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'white');
      break;
    case 7:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'orange');
      break;
    case 8:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "violet";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'violet');
      break;
    case 9:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'cyan');
      break;
    case 10:
      colorPreview.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--thumbColor', 'gray');
      break;


  }

}
```

```css
:root {
  --thumbColor: red;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: midnightblue;
}

.color-preview {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#color-picker {
  appearance: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, pink, yellow, blue, teal, black, white, orange, violet, cyan, gray);
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#color-picker::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: var(--thumbColor);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

#color-picker::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: var(--thumbColor);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input oninput="colorSlider()" id="color-picker" type="range" min="0" max="10">
  <div class="color-preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider using `oninput` instead of `onchange` so that the color updates as the user drags the `range` thumb/slider instead of only when the user lets go.

Comment: Thank you i changed to `oninput`

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show a Color Picker</h1>

<form action="">
  <label for="favcolor">Select your favorite color:</label>
  <input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I downvoted because this posting doesn’t answer the OP’s question at all - furthermore a color input cannot have an empty `value=“”` attribute.